# React js index design of text

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

Is there a way to do this in react tailwind

I tried checking on tailwind and there's no reference on the documentation

[image: Three column layout showing an index page]

```
A

Alfreds Futterkiste 2 1

Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados 1

H

Antonio Moreno Taquería 1

Around the Horn 1

B

B's Beverages 1

Berglunds snabbköp 1

Blauer See Delikatessen 1

Blondel père et fils 1 Bon app' 1

Bottom-Dollar Markets 1

Bólido Comidas preparadas 1

C

Cactus Comidas para llevar 1 
Centro comercial Moctezuma 1 
Chop-suey Chinese 1 
Comércio Mineiro 1 
Consolidated Holdings 1 

D

Die Wandernde Kuh 1 Drachenblut Delikatessen 1

Du monde entier 2

E

Eastern Connection 2

Ernst Handel 2

F

Familia Arquibaldo 2

Great Lakes Food Market 2

GROSELLA-Restaurante 2

Hanari Carnes 2

HILARIÓN-Abastos 2

Hungry Coyote Import Store 2

Queen Cozinha 4 QUICK-Stop 4

R

Rancho grande 4

Rattlesnake Canyon Grocery 4

Reggiani Caseifid 4

Hungry Owl All-Night Grocers 3

Ricardo Adocicados 4

I

Richter Supermarkt 4

Island Trading 3

K

Königlich Essen 3

L

La corne d'abondance 3

La maison d'Asie 3

Laughing Bacchus Wine Cellars 3 Lazy K Kountry Store 3 Lehmanns Marktstand 3

Let's Stop N Shop 3 LILA-Supermercado 3 LINO-Delicateses 3 Lonesome Pine Restaurant 3

M

Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti 3

Maison Dewey 3

Morgenstern Gesundkost 3 Mère Paillarde 3

N

North/South 3

FISSA Fabrica Inter. Salchichas S.A. 2

0

Folies gourmandes 2

Folk och fä HB 2

France restauration 2

Franchi S.p.A. 2

Frankenversand 2

Furia Bacalhau e Frutos do Mar 2

G

Galería del gastrónomo 2

Godos Cocina Típica 2

Océano Atlántico Ltda. 3

Old World Delicatessen 4

Ottilies Käseladen 4

P

Paris spécialités 4

Pericles Comidas dásicas 4

Piccolo und mehr 4 Princesa Isabel Vinhos 4

Romero y tomillo 4 S

Santé Gourmet 4 Save-a-lot Markets 4 Seven Seas Imports 4 Simons bistro 5 Split Rail Beer & Ale 5 Spécialités du monde 5 Suprêmes délices 5 T

The Big Cheese 5

The Cracker Box 5

Toms Spezialitäten 5

Tortuga Restaurante 5

Tradição Hipermercados 5

Trail's Head Gourmet Provisioners 5

V

Vaffeljernet 5

Victuailles en stock 5

Vins et alcools Chevalier 5

w

Wartian Herkku 5

Wellington Importadora 5

White Clover Markets 5

Wilman Kala 5

Wolski Zajazd 5

Q

Gourmet Lanchonetes 2

Que Delícia 4
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a list of places sorted by name, you could easily group them by initial character like so:

```
const grouped = restaurants.reduce<Record<string, Restaurant[]>>((grouped, entry) => {
  const initial = entry.name[0].toLowerCase()
  grouped[initial] ??= []
  grouped[initial].push(entry)
  return grouped
}, {})
// or in one line
const grouped = restaurants.reduce<Record<string, Restaurant[]>>((grouped, entry) => ((grouped[entry.name[0].toLowerCase()] ??= []).push(entry), grouped), {})
```

then render each group as a list with a heading

```
<>
  {Object.entries(grouped).map(([initial, restaurants]) => (
    <React.Fragment key={initial}>
      <h3>{initial.toUpperCase()}</h3>
      {restaurants.map(r => (
        <p key={r.id}>{r.name}</p>
      ))}
    </React.Fragment>
  ))}
</>
```